# How do I fix this code that should match fields between two files, and output various fields from each file? (awk)

Tags: bash, awk

Answered by many before, but I'm struggling somewhere here...

Code:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;a[$2]=$3;a[$3]=$4;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],a[$2],a[$3],$1,$3}' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

file1:

```
spot dog black male

felix cat white male
```

file 2:

```
spot dog good tall

felix cat bad small
```

output desired:

```
spot black male spot good

felix white male felix bad
```

actual output:

```
spot black spot good

felix white felix bad
```

`a[$3]` is not being printed, or wasn't assigned properly...

Comment: The values in column three in `file1` (`black` and `white`) don't appear in `file2` at all. How are you expecting to index them by column value when looking at `file2`? Also are your columns unique across the entire file? What's the intended mapping here exactly?

Comment: In non-code terms, I want to grab columns 1,3, and 4 from file1 (a array), where column 1 (a[$1]) of file1 matches column 1 of file2, I want to print the values in that row of a, along with the first and third field of that matched row in file2. Column 1 values only appear once in each file, other columns may not be unique. The actually data is paired end DNA sequencing data, with each end independently aligned. I need to re-pair the alignments by name, but only want certain columns from each of the two files.

Comment: Perhaps `join -j 1 -o 1.1,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.3 file1 file2` is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You want something more like this

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    # Don't need a value just presence in the array for the '$1 in a' check.
    a[$1]=""
    # The value of $3 may not be unique so that can't be a key but '$1,3' will be since $1 is unique.
    a[$1,3]=$3
    # Same here as for $3 above.
    a[$1,4]=$4
    next
}
$1 in a {
    print $1, a[$1,3], a[$1,4], $1, $3
}' file1 file2
```

The key here is that you can only use `$1` as your unique (and unique-fying) key and you have to use it for all the relevant fields.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I understand the first commenter's response now based on this as well.